# Is using python threading with gtk, and cmd ok?

Tags: python, multithreading, cmd, gtk

I have a script I wrote out of modifications of helloworld for gkt, and cmd.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import cmd
from gi.repository import Gtk
import threading

class GtkInterface(object):

    def __init__(self):
        win = Gtk.Window()
        win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
        win.show_all()
        self.window = win;
    def create_button(self):
        self.button = Gtk.Button(label="Click Here")
        self.button.connect("clicked", self.on_button_clicked)
        self.window.add(self.button)
        self.window.show_all()

    def on_button_clicked(self, widget):
        print 'something happened'
        return


class HelloWorld(cmd.Cmd):
    #Simple command processor example.
    prompt='>'
    def __init__(self, gtk_object):
        cmd.Cmd.__init__(self)
        # or cmd.Cmd.__init__(self)
        self.gtk_object = gtk_object

    def do_greet(self, line):
        print "hello"

    def do_setbutton(self, line):
        self.gtk_object.create_button()

    def do_exit(self, line):
        return True

gtk_o = GtkInterface()
hello = HelloWorld(gtk_o)

def worker(num):
    """thread worker function"""
    #print 'Worker: %s' % num
    hello.cmdloop()
    return

def worker2(num):
    Gtk.main()

threads = []


t = threading.Thread(target=worker, args=(1,))
threads.append(t)
t2 = threading.Thread(target=worker2, args=(2,))
threads.append(t2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    #HelloWorld().cmdloop()
    #Gtk.main()
    t.start()
    t2.start()
```

This works. What I'd like to know is this ok? Are there issues to look out for? This is my first time trying this so there are a lot of unknowns for me. I understand that both cmd, and gtk are blocking. The Gtk.main, and cmd loops work flawlessly so far. I'm just being cautious.

My first time using threading too. When cmd gets the command to setbutton the button is set. When the button is clicked 'something happened' prints. The  command line continues as if nothing out of the ordinary happened. I was really surprised at how seamless it all works. Yet I am still a little worried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GTK+ is not thread safe and there are a few problems with the example which may cause instability. The example loads GTK+ in the main thread, runs the GTK+ main loop in a different thread and creates GTK+ widgets  in yet another thread. All the GTK+ API calls should occur in the main thread with other threads communicating back to the main GUI thread by adding idle or timer callbacks. Have a read through the PyGObject threading wiki [1].

1. https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/PyGObject/Threading

Comment: Is this just a matter of keeping execution in order? Like something is running in a thread, but some other required data hasn't yet been produced from another thread?

Comment: I tried moving the Gtk main loop to the main thread,and it is working better. Another problem appeared which that solved. Switched accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

GTK has its' own threading library, and you need to be careful I think with complex applications : http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?req=show&file=faq20.006.htp - for instance when you have threads which update your GUI indepedently of the main thread.

In your example you do have a threaded application, although in fact your entire GTK application is running in a single thread - so you are ok.

Comment: Looks like it's all good then. Does it matter if gtk threads, or the standard threading module is used?

Comment: If you have a simple application where everything is done in a single thread, then you are ok. If you have an application where the GTK gui either starts or stops or needs to respond to other threads - then use the GTK threading library - it works in a very similar seamless way.